# How to access environment variables in gradle java build script

Tags: java, groovy, build, gradle

How can I access environment variables (either user level or system level) in gradle java build script.
I am new to gradle and I am trying to build my project using the gradle.
 Presently I have hardcoded the path of third party jars as shown in the script below

```
repositories {
   flatDir  {
           dirs 'D:\\lib'
   }
}
```

I have created an environment variable `"Third_Party" in enviroment variable`:

```
Third_Party=D:\lib
```

How can I use this variable i.e. "Third_Party" instead of hardcoding the library path in script.
Please tell the exact syntax

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try this way `System.getenv("env var name")` like

```
home = System.getenv('Third_Party')

task env_read << {
    println "$System.env.HOME"
    //Other way of accessing the environment variable.
    println  System.getenv('Third_Party')
}
```

Comment: Pls tell me how can I refer to this "home" inside "repositories" repositories { flatDir { dirs 'D:\lib' } }

Comment: Why not? It should be the following piece of code: `repositories { flatDir { dirs "${System.env.HOME}\lib" } }`

Comment: The first method worked for me to populate a manifest key from an env var. The second method produced: `> The value of a manifest attribute must not be null (Key=Implementation-Version).`