# How to add dependencies to other libraries on the hard, using environment variables, in an Android Studio project gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle

We have a very productive and robust SPL (software production line) for .NET platform to create web applications and HTTP services.
Now we want to import that knowledge into Android.

This is the scenario:

Developer A gets our android framework, and project A into the following paths:

```
D:\Android\Framework
D:\Android\ProjectA
```

And of course, project A should reuse code and stuff in Framework (layouts, java utilities, etc.)

Developer B's setup is:

```
C:\Users\Jack\AndroidStudioProjects\Framework
C:\Users\Jack\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectB
```

Again, project B reuses Framework libraries.

Both developer A and developer B have `AndroidProjectsRoot` environment variables defined in their systems. For developer A it refers to `D:\Android` and for developer B the path is `C:\Users\Jack\AndroidStudioProjects`.

It's a team-convention that we all have one root folder and get each project in a direct child directory of that root folder.

We use Android Studio and gradle, and here's the place where we're stuck. We can't make project A or B build using Framework libraries. Framework has these libraries:

```
 --jzp.framework
  --validation
  --http
  -- more libraries here
```

Inside project A/B's settings.gradle we have:

```
include ':app', ':http', ':validation' //, more includes here
project(':http').projectDir = new File('$System.getenv("")/Framework/http/libs')
project(':validation').projectDir = new File('$System.getenv("")/Framework/validation/libs')
// more directory configurations here
```

Then in the app's gradle we have:

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies here
    compile project(':http')
    compile project(':validation')
    // more compile statements here
}
```

However, project A/B won't build and we can't see our libraries packages inside our projects A/B etc.

What might be wrong? How to add dependencies to other modules on the hard drive, via environment variables?

Comment: Try this from the comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916294/how-to-access-environment-variables-in-gradle-java-build-script#comment44233512_27916429

Comment: @cricket_007, where should we add that line? In the top-level build gradle?

Comment: That depends if you need project dependency or only app dependency

Comment: What we need is very simple. Code reuse. One of the most fundamental principles of software engineering. DRY. And also, breaking things into coherent sub-things, to divide and conquer. Could you guide us on both directions? Project dependency and module dependency and ...